# How to enforce global uniqueness in a User table in CosmosDB

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I need to create a `User` table that at minimum looks like this:

```
public class User
{
  public Guid Id {get; set;}
  public string Username {get; set;}
  public string EmailAddress {get; set;}
  public DateTime CreatedOn {get; set;}
}
```

I'm currently writing all data to `CosmosDB` (SQL API). The problem is I need to add a unique index policy to `Username` and `EmailAddress` across all users. Since `CosmosDB` is designed with scaling out in mind, I'd need to partition this container. If I do so, I cannot enforce uniqueness across partitions.

Currently, my partition key is `Id`. If I change my partition key to `Username` or `EmailAddress`, I fear that changing these fields can potentially result in users being deleted (e.g. delete old username and insert new username would be two separate transactions if the usernames belong to different partitions, which means there is no atomicity.).

Is there a `CosmosDB` solution to this problem that I cannot think of? I can move this part to `SQL Server`, but I'll end up maintaining a large table over time. Also, since I'm using `Azure Functions` for server processing, shipping with EF DLLs makes the app size unnecessarily large.

Comment: How many users are you anticipating? Can't you put all users in a single partition?

Comment: It depends on how successful the app becomes. A single partition holds 20 gigs. If all goes well, I expect I'll need a lot more than that capacity in the future. Right now, I'm keeping everything in SQL Server, but I don't like the fact that EF dlls are making my serverless app too big.

Comment: Another thought - Can you make the email address's domain as PartitionKey? In that case all gmail users will go in one partition and all hotmail users will go in other partition.

Comment: I think this will lead to poor partitioning strategy since more than half of all emails are gmail. Ideally, partition keys should be evenly divided for high throughput (hence I used a `Guid`).

Comment: With Guid, you get exactly one user per partition. It is not desirable either :).

Comment: Sorry. My mind went to other containers I have whose partition key is the user id. For those containers, it makes sense because they have user-specific activity. For the `User` container, I agree that a `Guid` isn't great because of excessive partitioning. However, I think Azure can decide to host multiple logical partitions in the same physical partition, so I'm not sure if this is necessarily a bad thing?

Answer (score 1):

Make a synthetic `partitionKey` property and assign it a value, for example `partitionKey:users_list`. there you can keep all users `id's` and `emails`:

```
{
   id: guid,
   email: user@whatever.com,
   partitionKey: "users_list"
}
```

make a stored procedure that registers new users and before saving a user it checks no other user exists with the same email address within "users_list" partition.

if your documents are 1kb (and i see no reason to be more) then your partition can hold up to 20 million users. if you need more, its easy to make this partition key granular but still being sure you keep all of your users in a very small number of partitions. like, 5 partitions give you 100 million users.
For example, you can have `partitionKey` granular by time, by world region, by starting letters, whatever you find suitable...

Answer (score 0):

Make a synthetic partition key of `UserName_EmailAddress` and it will be unique.

Comment: If you don't want to change the partitioning of the main container, you can do this on a separate container that serves as a "global index" enforcing uniqueness and providing optimized lookup of ID by (UserName,EmailAddress).

Comment: @DavidBrowne-Microsoft, what if I reach the partition limit which I believe is set to 20 GBs? Does MS increase this limit on demand via, say, a support ticket?

Comment: Mark, I need to allow users to change their username and email address as they wish. Making changes to the partition key is a 2-step process and not atomic (assuming two different logical partitions are used).

Comment: @user246392  That's really different question.  But basically, 1) choose a partition key so that never happens, or 2) replace old docs for the logical partition when full, or 3) add a suffix to the partition key to spread the data over multiple logical partitions when full.

Comment: Yes, this is a trade off you'll need to make in having to manage consistency client-side. I would also use a tombstone flag rather than delete as it allows you to roll back.